# Receiving and sending using node.js and websockets

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, websocket

**Client code:**

```
<body>
    <input type=text id="input">
</body>
<script>
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://chat-mmnnww123.c9users.io');

    /*AFTER CONNECTION*/
    $('#input').change(function(){
        connection.send(this.value);
        $('#input').val("");
        alert("DONE");
    });

    connection.onmessage = function(e){
        alert(e.data);
    };
</script>
```

This code just send message write in the `input` to the server website.

**Server code:**

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
var server = ws.createServer(function(conn){
    console.log("New Connection");

    //on text function
    conn.on("text", function(str){
        /*
            I want to send this str to agent.html page
        */
        conn.sendText("Message send : " + str.toUpperCase());

    });


    //closing the connection
    conn.on("close", function(){
        console.log("connection closed");
    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

This is the server code which SHOULD take the value in **str** and pass it to the **agent.html** page.

Now all I want is to take that **str** value and pass it to page agent.html that I haven't created yet. This page will help the agent to see the client message.
It should be instant and without refreshing the page.

Comment: _"Now all I want is to take that str value and pass it to page agent.html that I haven't created yet."_ Not certain what you mean by "haven't created yet"? What is issue with `js` at Question?

Comment: I want to pass the **str** value to a page called agent.html

Comment: What is issue with `js` at Question?

Comment: Why not just use a realtime data delivery service to do this, it will be far more robust, scale, and simplify things for you...  **Disclaimer: I am the co-founder of [Ably - simple better realtime](https://www.ably.io), and I created Ably to solve exactly these sorts of problems easily, reliably and cost-effectively**